# Unable to print date to json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm writing code to print date directly from index.js to data.json but getting **data is not defined** error.

I did:

> npm init
>
> npm i jsonfile

**index.js**

```
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
const moment = require('moment');
       
const FILE_PATH = './data.json';

const DATE = moment().format();

const date = {

   date: DATE
 }

 jsonfile.writeFile(FILE_PATH, data);    //Error(here)
                              
 //ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Comment: You don't declare `data` anywhare in your code... Do you mean `date.data` ?

Comment: Maybe you have a small typo here ´´´´ jsonfile.writeFile(FILE_PATH, data); ´´´´ instead **date** you set **data **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have simple typo mistake just change `date` instead of `data`

```
const date = {

   date: DATE
}

jsonfile.writeFile(FILE_PATH, date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never actually define the variable `data`, which is the issue. I think you want to write `date` to the file like this instead:

```
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
const moment = require('moment');

const FILE_PATH = './data.json';

const DATE = moment().format();

const date = {

   date: DATE
 }

 jsonfile.writeFile(FILE_PATH, date); // Change data to date
```